# Unable to get any version of Ubuntu to run, except 12.10

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, 14.04, system-installation, screen-corruption

I have wiped the terabyte hard drive of my desktop to perform a clean dual boot install of Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu. I have dual booted this machine in the past without issue.

Unfortunately, the only version that will install in a stable fashion is **12.10** and I'm aware that support is soon to be discontinued. I have tried **12.04 LTS** and **14.04 LTS** (32 and 64 bit).

I'm installing from USB. I'm able to install every time but the system crashes at the splash screen or just after log in to the system. In every case the crash is followed by weird graphics and necessitates a hard reboot. Prior to this clean install I had recently attempted to upgrade to **13.10** but had frequent crashes with the same odd graphics behavior so I went back to **12.10**.

I'm able to install and run Windows 7 which has been stable on this machine. There are no performance issues playing media or running games via Steam so there does not seem to be any major hardware issue.

Obviously I'm hopeful someone can help, but I'm also very curious as to why **12.10** is completely stable and no other version of Ubuntu is on this system.   System spec's as follows:

- **AMD Athlon II 3100MHz, quad core**
- **4GB RAM**
- **NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE graphics card**

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: You should install **14.04 LTS** (or **13.10**) 32bit. Then research setup (and known issues) for that graphics cards in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It seems it was that pesky graphics card.  I don't know why I had convinced myself  it was something else.   Feeling mildly embarrassed for posting about such a well known issue. Also, I don't know how to mark this question closed or answered so I don't waste anyone else's time?  Thanks again.